# c# xml comment, cref can't reference method defined in base class

Tags: c#, xml-comments

In my codebase I have a method defined in a base class, the base class is inherited, but the method is not yet overridden. This method will very likely be overridden in the future to add to the base implementation.

My setup looks a bit like this:

```
public abstract class BaseFoo
{
    public virtual void Bar()
    {
        //default implementation
    }
}

public class RealFoo : BaseFoo
{
    //extra code, does *NOT YET* override Bar but might in the future
}

public class DependentClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Uses <see cref="RealFoo.Bar"/> to do some magic
    /// </summary>
    public void SomeMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

Since it's very likely that Bar will be overridden in the future, I would like to future proof my xmldoc and reference `RealFoo.Bar` instead of `BaseFoo.Bar`.

When I call `RealFoo.Bar()` in my code, no errors occur. When I do so in a cref attribute I get the following warning:

> Warning   CS1574  XML comment has cref attribute 'Bar' that could not be
>   resolved.

Am I doing something wrong here or is this just a limitation of cref?

I'm using visual studio 2017, targeting netstandard2.0 and net452, and I have XML documentation enabled in my csproj.

Comment: What .Net version / compiler / Visual Studio are you using? I tested it here and did not get this warning. The tooltip appears: "Uses RealFoo.Bar to do some magic"

Comment: @Tony did you turn on XML compilation in the project settings -> Build -> XML documentation file?

Comment: No, let me try that. on .Net Core 2.1 , Visual Studio 2017 15.8.0 Preview 2.0

Comment: warning CS1591: Missing XML comment for publicly visible type or member ...
 'BaseFoo', 'BaseFoo.Bar()', 'RealFoo', 'DependentClass'

Comment: The XML was generated sucessfully.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can suppress this warning, but the XmlDoc output will mark it with an error.

```xml
<member name="M:MyApplication.DependentClass.SomeMethod">
    <summary>
        Uses <see cref="!:RealFoo.Bar"/> to do some magic
        <!--            ^- indicates an error -->
    </summary>
</member>
```

Alternatively, if you're pretty sure that you're going to override the method in the future, and you are intending to generate documentation with the XML output, I would just implement it in `RealFoo` as `public override void Bar() => base.Bar();` until you want a new implementation.

Comment: I might just implement it or change the cref reference to a plain text without cref, I was however wondering why this warning occurs. Is it a bug or just a limitation?

Comment: @Rob My money is on limitation, I can see why you wouldn't want to crawl an inheritance hierarchy to find a virtual method, and it would be a bit unclear in documentation if the link referenced one type but really went to another type in the hierarchy.

Comment: Accepted this answer since it's the closest answer I got, I guess it's by design. I worked around it by using 'Uses RealFoo.Bar (implemented by <see cref="BaseFoo.Bar"/>) to do some magic'

Answer (score 8):

In this case I just statically write ClassName.Member, which does the trick.

```
/// <summary>
/// Uses <see cref="BaseFoo.Bar"/> to do some magic
/// </summary>
public void SomeMethod()
{

}
```

It looks like .NET Xml-Doc does not know about inheritance.